# How to run Spark application on Spark cluster from Servlet's doGet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark application from servlet on cluster mode.

When using `spark-submit` to `local` as well as to a cluster mode, it works fine. But it does not when running from Servlet's `doGet()` method on cluster mode.

Here is the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 24, 192.168.1.38): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ngi.spark.manipulator.util.UtilSparkRDD$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:66)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1897)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1897)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1897)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
```

I am deploying my servlet on Apache Tomcat and the above SparkException happens when sending a GET request to run my Spark program.

Here is the class in which exception is coming:

```
public class UtilSparkRDD implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8077220930563809961L;

    public JavaRDD<Row> getDataFromFile(JavaSparkContext sparkContext,
            String filePath, final String rowDelimeter, final String  fieldDelimeter) {
        JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = sparkContext.textFile(filePath).flatMap(
                new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8248977466300597565L;

                    public Iterable<String> call(String data) {
                        return Arrays.asList(data.split(rowDelimeter));
                    }
                });

        // Convert records of the RDD to Rows.
        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = javaRDD.map(
                new Function<String, Row>() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4608543635003549767L;

                    public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
                        Object[] fields = record.split(fieldDelimeter);
                        return RowFactory.create(fields);


                    }   
                });
        return rowRDD;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real cause lies in the place **where** and **how** you create an instance of SparkContext. It's quite common to grab too much for serializer to send over the wire to executors to launch tasks.

`ngi.spark.manipulator.util.UtilSparkRDD` is the fully-qualified package name for the `UtilSparkRDD` class, isn't it?

The entire class is serialized and sent to executors, but they don't have it locally, on their CLASSPATH, and the deserialization fails.

A solution is to have a static or transient fields that should not be sent over the wire, and to be precise it's necessary to see the entire `ngi.spark.manipulator.util.UtilSparkRDD`.

Comment: I want to create the spark context in init method so that it would not create spark context every time, so whenever I hit do get method It take context from the global variable and pass that to use every time.
but it is not working on cluster while working great on local mode.

Comment: You're creating a `SparkContext` in `init` and I **guess** your servlet is indeed initialized which means that the context has been created. The exception is thrown **only** when you execute `GET` and that's something you haven't yet showed in the attached code. Can you show the entire doGet where you execute an action (that triggers jobs that lead to the exception)?

Comment: In doGet method I have paste the code of my main class except code for creating spark context. so basically servlet doget method act like I am running my application.(Also it is working in local mode)

Answer (score 0):

I added the jar in my spark context...and solved my problem.

```
sparkContext.addJar("/home/ngi/ManipulatorNew-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
```